# Gridster resize stop id

Tags: jquery, gridster

I have a gridster grid working and I'm trying to get the id of the `<li>` item that has been resized.

`resize: {
    enabled: true,
    stop: function (e, ui, $widget) {

        //Need the id of the item that was just resized
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my problem was coming from the fact that I had serialized parameters in gridster:

`serialize_params: function ($w, wgd) {
    return {
         DataTypeId: wgd.el[0].id,
         Column: wgd.col,
         Row: wgd.row,
         SizeX: wgd.size_x,
         SizeY: wgd.size_y
        }
},`

so in my "stop" event I was able to use:

`var newDimensions = this.serialize($widget)[0]
newDimensions.DataTypeId`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered:

$widget.attr('id');

Comment: Any idea how to get it id for a stop event on a drag (not resize) ? That function does not pass $widget you see.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. You can get it from the ui object like this: ui.$player.attr('id');